# Need to avoid renaming large 90GB mongo database. Can I proxy one db name to another on the server?

Tags: mongodb

My org has a large mongo database, about 90GB, that we restore from production to staging every night with raw file backup. It is named one thing in production but needs to be named something else in staging and dev environments. The database is named "myorg-production" but we'd like to name it "myorg-staging" in other environments.

My team would like to have the database renamed in our staging environments so accidents don't happen on the real production database. If the names are the same and both say production it's likely to confuse at least 1 team member at some point and cost us.

Changing the name in Mongo (2.6 at least) is difficult especially with a large database. You essentially need to export and import a whole new db to achieve a simple rename.

We'd like to somehow proxy requests with a database name alias. Is there an app or tool out there, internal or external to mongo, that can proxy the traffic based on the db name?

Anyone have any idea how I could solve this without having to copy the entire database in the process?

Comment: What version of MongoDB server are you actually using? You mention 2.6, but it is not clear if that is a comment on historical behaviour since 2.6 reached end of life in October, 2016. Assuming you are likely using a newer version of MongoDB, what storage engine are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.6. This is a 90GB database. It is not easy to just move to 4.x over night.

Comment: Reading [this JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701) makes me think that there's probably a better way to manage this in your Dev environment than renaming the database.

Comment: Yeah I read that too... that's why I turned my attention to a proxy of some kind. But you may be right.